# Ruby %w empty value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How do I add empty string as a select option into `%w(Mr Ms Mrs Miss)`?

I can do `['', 'Mr', 'Ms', 'Mrs', 'Miss']` but I would like to use `%w`. Thx!

Comment: You can pass `include_blank: true` to the `select` [form helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use [`unshift`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.5/Array.html#method-i-unshift) it is prepended object to the front:

```
=> %w(Mr Ms Mrs Miss).unshift ""
#> ["", "Mr", "Ms", "Mrs", "Miss"]
```

Pretty version without brackets.

Ok for your update:

```
=> %W(#{} Mr Ms Mrs Miss)
#> ["", "Mr", "Ms", "Mrs", "Miss"]
```

explain:

- `%W` - allow interpolation
- `%w` - not allow interpolation
- `#{}` - empty string

Comment: yeah! thought of %W, but didn't use # :) I'll accept answer in a moment!

Comment: `%W` enables not only interpolation, but also escape sequences, like `\n`, which are otherwise escaped by `%w`. Interesting, these literals still surprise me at times o_o

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
%w(Mr Ms Mrs Miss).unshift('')
["", "Mr", "Ms", "Mrs", "Miss"]
```